# Rails 2.3.2 app and rails 3 app on the same machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I upgraded to the latest Rails v3.1.3. And everything is fine, I'm able to run the 2.3 version of one website *and* the app for v3.1.3.

However I couldn't **move it to a new machine**, I installed all the required gems with

```
bundle install
```

and just cannot start Thin with the 2.3.2 version. I can only run the v3 apps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go read about [RVM](https://rvm.io), and try to configure you machine according to the instructions given there.

Comment: Thanks, I found this video, will try to follow http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

Answer (score 1):

As @Syed Aslam said the ideal way of doing is using [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/), but you may set bundler to your Rails 2.x project (because rails 3.x already have bundler..) and run both your projects in the same machine (actually currently I'm doing that).

Following is a tutorial how setting up bundle with [Rails 2.x](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html).